# SSIS Converting GetDate()-1 to EPOCH

Tags: sql, ssis, epoch

Wondering if you could help with a query please. I am trying to automate data import from a cloud CRM using API connection. To perform an incremental load, i would like import only records that were modified yesterday (EPOCH format). Any way i could do this using SSIS expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateDiff function to convert date to Epoch format and use the value to build the API URL in a variable. Not sure which version of SSIS you are using but can use Script task to achieve it. If there is an option, its better to code it in C# and schedule it as a Windows service or batch job.

```
DATEDIFF(s, "1970-01-01 00:00:00", @yesterdaydate)
```